# Navigating from table view to table view to table view (iOS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I am having difficulties defining a navigation between several tables. I am using the navigation template for iOS apps. From The RootViewController (RootViewController.xib already contains a table), I can navigate to another table view (in the interface builder I was able to connect the IBOutlet with the custom UITableViewController):

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {
    xxxTableViewController *teeTimeTableVC;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet xxxTableViewController *xxxTableVC;
```

In RootViewController.m the following line works fine:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.xxxTableVC animated:YES];
```

The interface builder does not let me connect the IBOutlet in the second XIB file (let's say xxxTableViewController) with the next UITableViewController.

```
@interface xxxTableViewController : UITableViewController 
    <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    yyyTableViewController *yyyTableVC;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet yyyTableViewController *yyyTableVC;
```

In xxxTableViewController.m the following line display a warning:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.yyyTableVC animated:YES];
```

In the code, I also get a warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct yyyViewController *', expected 'struct UIViewController *' when passing argument 1 of 'pushViewController:animated:' from distinct Objective-C type

Am I trying to implement a bad concept? Is it only possible this way directy from the RootViewController? Both controller classes seem to be identical:

```
@interface yyyTableViewController : UITableViewController 
    <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>{
}
```

Can please anybody give me a hint? Do I need to use different UI elements or implement another protocol?

Thank you, Patric

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your second controller doesn't have the `navigationController` member, so the compiler is complaining when you're trying to use it. You'll need to create this member yourself, and pass it to the class during initialization.

Comment: Hello Andy. Thank you for your answer. I think I disagree or I do not completely understand. The navigationController member seem to be inherited from UITableViewController which inherits it from UIViewController.

Comment: The other warning warning is maybe more explicit: xxxTableViewController.m: warning: Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer types sending 'yyyTableViewController *' to parameter of type 'UIViewController *'
But that also does not explain the issues with the interface builder. Is there maybe a tutorial available which demonstrates navigation between more than 2 tables?

Comment: @user690110 Looking at your warning again, it almost sounds like you aren't including the header for yyyTableViewController, so the compiler can't figure out the type of yyyTableVC. I'm not sure what else would cause that warning.